# ES6 Classes: How do I get `this.foo` property in base class constructor assigned to derived class prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

The issue I'm having is that when class B is instantiated, if I pass in `options.foo` on B, `this.foo` assigns to class A instead of class B.

I'd like to create a base class (in this case class A) that will assign `this.foo` to the derived class prototype (in this case class B).

```
class A {

  constructor(options = {}) {

    this.foo = options.foo

  }

}

class B extends A {

  constructor(options = {}) {

    super(options)

  } 

}

var b = new B()
console.log(b.prototype.foo) // undefined
```

Comment: How should that be possible? `new B(...)` returns a single object. Are you saying that object does not have a property `foo`? It's unclear to me what you mean by "assigns to class A instead of class B". Nothing is assigned to the *class* here.

Comment: I don't know what this means. Nothing is assigned "to the class". The object you're constructing gets its `foo` property set to `options.foo`, whatever that may evaluate to.

Comment: `b` doesn't even have a `prototype` property. Where do you expect that to come from? Your code explicitly says that that `foo` should be assigned to the newly created object, i.e. `b.foo`. If you are not very familiar with `this`, constructor functions and prototypes, I recommend to read [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes).

Answer (score 0):

`this.foo` is an instance property, it is assigned to `b`. It won't ever be assigned to a `.prototype` object (where it would be shared amongst instances).

If you want properties that are assigned to classes, you should have a look at the `static` keyword.